# Triangles with texture in processing

Tags: java, processing

I have a code in processing which contains points moving randomly. Those points seek the ball and start triangulate (shaping triangles). I want to display on them a folder of sequences images with opacity. So every time that an triangle is shaped will be textured with an image.
I have tried to use texture and loadimage function but it seems that the problem is that triangles is rendered rapidly with various points and texture can not be seen properly.

```
import processing.opengl.*;
float r1, r2;
void setup()
{
  size(800, 800, OPENGL);
 for (int j=0; j<numAgents; j++)
    agents[j]=new agent();
  for (int i=0; i<numMovers; i++)
    movers[i]=new Mover();
  smooth();
}
void draw()
{
  background(0);

  for (int i=0; i<numMovers; i++)
  {
    movers[i].update();
    movers[i].checkEdges();
    movers[i].display();
    int closestAgentNumber=-1;
    for (int j=0; j<numAgents; j++)
    {
      agents[j].checkEdges();
      agents[j].display();

      agents[j].update();
      agents[j].repel();

      float d = dist(agents[j].location.x, agents[j].location.y, movers[i].location.x, movers[i].location.y );

      if (d < 100) {
        closestAgentNumber=j; 
      }
      if (d<200)
      {
        agents[j].behaviour=1;
        agents[j].follow(movers[i].location.x, movers[i].location.y);
        movers[i].hit = true;
      }
      else if (d>100) {
        movers[i].hit = false;

        agents[j].behaviour=0;
      }

    }
  }
}
int numAgents= 100;
agent[]agents =new agent[numAgents];

class agent
{
  PVector location;
  PVector velocity;
  PVector acceleration;
  float topspeed;
  float r1, r2;
  // boolean connect=false;
  int behaviour;
  boolean follow=false;
  //boolean follow= false;
  agent()
  {
    float speed=800;

    if (behaviour==0)
    {

      location= new PVector(random(0, speed), random(0, speed));
      velocity= new PVector(1, 1);
      acceleration= new PVector( random(-0.01, 0.01), random(-0.01, 0.01));
      acceleration.normalize();
      topspeed=5;
    }
    else if (behaviour==1)
    {


      // connect=true;
    }
    // Set to acceleration
  }
  void follow(float x, float y)
  {
    if (follow==true)
    { 

      // follow==true;
      // Our algorithm for calculating acceleration:
      PVector moverPos = new PVector(x, y);
      PVector dir = PVector.sub(moverPos, location);  // Find vector pointing towards mouse
      dir.normalize();     // Normalize
      dir.mult(4);       // Scale 
      acceleration = dir;
    }
  }
  void update()
  {
    velocity.add(acceleration);
    velocity.limit(topspeed);
    location.add(velocity);
  }

  void display()
  {
    pushMatrix();
    translate(location.x, location.y);
    if (behaviour==1)
    {
      fill(255, 0, 0);
    }
    else if ( behaviour==0)
    {
      fill(255, 255, 255);
    }
    ellipse(0, 0, 4, 4);
    strokeWeight(1);

    popMatrix();
  }

  void checkEdges() 
  {

    if (location.x < 0) {
      location.x = 0;
      velocity.x *= -1;
      acceleration.mult(0.001);
    }
    if (location.x > 800) {
      location.x = 800;
      velocity.x *= -1;
      acceleration.mult(0.001);
    }
    if (location.y < 0) {
      location.y = 0;
      velocity.y *= -1;
      acceleration.mult(0.001);
    }
    if (location.y > 800) {
      location.y = 800;
      velocity.y *= -1;
      acceleration.mult(0.001);
    }
  }
  void repel()
  {

    for (int i=0; i<numAgents; i++) {

      if ((agents[i].behaviour==1))

      {
        int k;

        k=1;
        for (int j=0; j<numAgents; j++)
        {


          //--------------
          // float dm = agents[i].location.dist(agents[k].location);
          float dm = dist(agents[j].location.x, agents[j].location.y, agents[i].location.x, agents[i].location.y);
          if (dm < 50) {
            agents[i].velocity.mult(-1);
            agents[i].acceleration.mult(0.5);
            agents[j].velocity.mult(-1);
            agents[j].acceleration.mult(0.5);
          }
          else if (behaviour==0)
          {
            agents[i].velocity.mult(1);
            agents[j].velocity.mult(1);
          }



          //float dm = dist(agents[i].location.x, agents[i].location.y, agents[j].location.x, agents[j].location.y);
          // float dm = agents[i].location.dist(agents[j].location);
          // int clr=(int) map (dm,0,100,200,0);
          if (dm<180 && dm>100)


          {
            if ( k<2)
            {
              //println(dm);
              //stroke(255,0,0);
              r1 = agents[j].location.x;
              r2 = agents[j].location.y;

              k=k+1;
            }
            else
            {
              //fill(random(255),random(255),random(255),random(0,20));

              //stroke(0,50);
              // texture(A);

              //fill(random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0, 40));

              // stroke(140, 50);  
              fill(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 10));

              stroke(140, 50);
              beginShape();


              //texture();
              //  image(A,agents[i].location.x, agents[i].location.y);
              vertex(agents[i].location.x, agents[i].location.y);
              vertex(r1, r2);
              vertex(agents[j].location.x, agents[j].location.y);
              endShape(CLOSE);
              j=300;
            }
          }
        }
        /*void triangulate()
         {

         fill(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 40));

         stroke(140, 50);
         for (int i=0; i<numAgents; i++)
         {
         //gens[i].connect==true)
         //if(! agents[i].connect)

         if (agents[i].behaviour==1)

         {
         //println(agents[i]);
         int k;

         k=1;

         for (int j=0; j<numAgents; j++)
         {
         float dm = dist(agents[i].location.x, agents[i].location.y, agents[j].location.x, agents[j].location.y);
         // float dm = agents[i].location.dist(agents[j].location);
         // int clr=(int) map (dm,0,100,200,0);
         if (dm<180 && dm>100)

         {
         if ( k<2)
         {
         //println(dm);
         //stroke(255,0,0);
         }
         }
         }
         }*/
      }
    }
  }
}
int numMovers= 1;
Mover[]movers= new Mover[numMovers];

class Mover
{

  PVector location;
  PVector velocity;
  PVector acceleration;
  float topspeed;
  boolean hit = false;

  Mover() 
  {
    float spead = 800;
    location = new PVector(random(0,spead),random(0,spead));
    velocity = new PVector(0,0);
    acceleration = new PVector(random(-1,1),random(-1,1));//random initial acceleration
    topspeed = 4;
  }



  void update() 
  {
    // Motion 101!  Velocity changes by acceleration.  Location changes by velocity.
    velocity.add(acceleration);
    velocity.limit(topspeed);
    location.add(velocity);
  }


  void display()
  {
    pushMatrix();
  translate(location.x,location.y);
  //fill(102,0,155,random(120,160));
  //fill(32,225,245,127 + sin(frameCount*.01) * 127);
  if(hit) fill(255,10,96,120);
  else   
  fill(3,225,190,random(50,127));
  ellipse(0,0,30,30);
  noStroke();
  popMatrix();
  }


  void checkEdges() 
  {

    if(location.x < 0){
      location.x = 0;
      velocity.x *= -1;
      acceleration.mult(0.001);
    }
    if(location.x > 800){
      location.x = 800;
      velocity.x *= -1;
      acceleration.mult(0.001);

    }
    if(location.y < 0){
      location.y = 0;
      velocity.y *=- 1;
      acceleration.mult(0.001);

    }
    if(location.y > 800){
      location.y = 800;
      velocity.y *= -1;
      acceleration.mult(0.001);

    }




  }

}
```

Comment: yes. i am trying to do that but i dont know . its my first time using this site. can i sent it to you?

Comment: i make the following <pre>...(my code)...</pre>

Comment: and i try using <pre><code> .....</pre></code>  but still reported as a problematic syntax.

Comment: Paste your code, select it, then click the **{}** symbol from the editing options icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use 3 Processing functions for this:

1. [tint()](http://processing.org/reference/tint_.html) - which you'll use for transparency (e.g. tint(255,127); will make the image/texture 50% transparent (127 of 255) )
2. [texture()](http://processing.org/reference/texture_.html) - this sets texture to a shape(beginShape(),endShape() block). You pass call it after `beginShape()` and then you pass two additional arguments when calling `vertex()`, which are your texture coordinates
3. [textureMode()](http://processing.org/reference/textureMode_.html) - If you always know the size of your texture image, this is optional, but it's handy to know about this. By default the texture mode is set to IMAGE meaning that for a 100x100 px image that you will map to a 300 units long quad for example, you will map the vertex corner positions with the texture coordinates as in the example bellow.

default texture mode (textureMode(IMAGE))

```
//assumes tex is already initialized/loaded PImage
beginShape();
texture(tex);
vertex(-150,-150,0,    0,  0);//top-left
vertex( 150,-150,0,  100,  0);//top-right
vertex( 150, 150,0,  100,100);//bottom-right
vertex(-150, 150,0,    0,100);//bottom-left
endShape();
```

The other option is to use NORMALIZED mode, which instead of actual pixel values, takes normalized values (between 0.0 and 1.0), so the above example in NORMALIZED mode is:

```
beginShape();
texture(tex);
vertex(-150,-150,0,    0.0,0.0);//top-left
vertex( 150,-150,0,    1.0,0.0);//top-right
vertex( 150, 150,0,    1.0,1.0);//bottom-right
vertex(-150, 150,0,    0.0,1.0);//bottom-left
endShape();
```

`textureMode()` is called usually once in `setup()` and the advantage is you won't have to worry about knowing all the dimensions of all your textures, especially when you use more than one texture in your sketch.

So, back to your code, you need to initialize the texture like so:

```
tex = loadImage("yourTextureImage.png");
  textureMode(NORMALIZED);
```

and later in `repel()` function when you draw your shape, you would do this:

```
beginShape();
              tint(255,127);  
              texture(tex);
              vertex(agents[i].location.x, agents[i].location.y,0.0,0.0);//aditional u,v coordinates 0,0 - top left of texture
              vertex(r1, r2,1.0,0.0);//top right texture coordinate
              vertex(agents[j].location.x, agents[j].location.y,1.0,1.0);//bottom right texture coordinat
              endShape(CLOSE);
```

So the full code would look like this:

```
import processing.opengl.*;
float r1, r2;
PImage tex;
void setup()
{
  size(800, 800, OPENGL);
 for (int j=0; j<numAgents; j++)
    agents[j]=new agent();
  for (int i=0; i<numMovers; i++)
    movers[i]=new Mover();
  tex = loadImage("yourImage.png");
  textureMode(NORMALIZED);
  smooth();
}
void draw()
{
  background(0);

  for (int i=0; i<numMovers; i++)
  {
    movers[i].update();
    movers[i].checkEdges();
    movers[i].display();
    int closestAgentNumber=-1;
    for (int j=0; j<numAgents; j++)
    {
      agents[j].checkEdges();
      agents[j].display();

      agents[j].update();
      agents[j].repel();

      float d = dist(agents[j].location.x, agents[j].location.y, movers[i].location.x, movers[i].location.y );

      if (d < 100) {
        closestAgentNumber=j; 
      }
      if (d<200)
      {
        agents[j].behaviour=1;
        agents[j].follow(movers[i].location.x, movers[i].location.y);
        movers[i].hit = true;
      }
      else if (d>100) {
        movers[i].hit = false;

        agents[j].behaviour=0;
      }

    }
  }
}
int numAgents= 100;
agent[]agents =new agent[numAgents];

class agent
{
  PVector location;
  PVector velocity;
  PVector acceleration;
  float topspeed;
  float r1, r2;
  // boolean connect=false;
  int behaviour;
  boolean follow=false;
  //boolean follow= false;
  agent()
  {
    float speed=800;

    if (behaviour==0)
    {

      location= new PVector(random(0, speed), random(0, speed));
      velocity= new PVector(1, 1);
      acceleration= new PVector( random(-0.01, 0.01), random(-0.01, 0.01));
      acceleration.normalize();
      topspeed=5;
    }
    else if (behaviour==1)
    {


      // connect=true;
    }
    // Set to acceleration
  }
  void follow(float x, float y)
  {
    if (follow==true)
    { 

      // follow==true;
      // Our algorithm for calculating acceleration:
      PVector moverPos = new PVector(x, y);
      PVector dir = PVector.sub(moverPos, location);  // Find vector pointing towards mouse
      dir.normalize();     // Normalize
      dir.mult(4);       // Scale 
      acceleration = dir;
    }
  }
  void update()
  {
    velocity.add(acceleration);
    velocity.limit(topspeed);
    location.add(velocity);
  }

  void display()
  {
    pushMatrix();
    translate(location.x, location.y);
    if (behaviour==1)
    {
      fill(255, 0, 0);
    }
    else if ( behaviour==0)
    {
      fill(255, 255, 255);
    }
    ellipse(0, 0, 4, 4);
    strokeWeight(1);

    popMatrix();
  }

  void checkEdges() 
  {

    if (location.x < 0) {
      location.x = 0;
      velocity.x *= -1;
      acceleration.mult(0.001);
    }
    if (location.x > 800) {
      location.x = 800;
      velocity.x *= -1;
      acceleration.mult(0.001);
    }
    if (location.y < 0) {
      location.y = 0;
      velocity.y *= -1;
      acceleration.mult(0.001);
    }
    if (location.y > 800) {
      location.y = 800;
      velocity.y *= -1;
      acceleration.mult(0.001);
    }
  }
  void repel()
  {

    for (int i=0; i<numAgents; i++) {

      if ((agents[i].behaviour==1))

      {
        int k;

        k=1;
        for (int j=0; j<numAgents; j++)
        {


          //--------------
          // float dm = agents[i].location.dist(agents[k].location);
          float dm = dist(agents[j].location.x, agents[j].location.y, agents[i].location.x, agents[i].location.y);
          if (dm < 50) {
            agents[i].velocity.mult(-1);
            agents[i].acceleration.mult(0.5);
            agents[j].velocity.mult(-1);
            agents[j].acceleration.mult(0.5);
          }
          else if (behaviour==0)
          {
            agents[i].velocity.mult(1);
            agents[j].velocity.mult(1);
          }



          //float dm = dist(agents[i].location.x, agents[i].location.y, agents[j].location.x, agents[j].location.y);
          // float dm = agents[i].location.dist(agents[j].location);
          // int clr=(int) map (dm,0,100,200,0);
          if (dm<180 && dm>100)


          {
            if ( k<2)
            {
              //println(dm);
              //stroke(255,0,0);
              r1 = agents[j].location.x;
              r2 = agents[j].location.y;

              k=k+1;
            }
            else
            {
              //fill(random(255),random(255),random(255),random(0,20));

              //stroke(0,50);
              // texture(A);

              //fill(random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0, 40));

              // stroke(140, 50);  
              fill(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 10));

              stroke(140, 50);
              beginShape();
              tint(255,127);  
              texture(tex);
              vertex(agents[i].location.x, agents[i].location.y,0.0,0.0);//aditional u,v coordinates 0,0 - top left of texture
              vertex(r1, r2,1.0,0.0);//top right texture coordinate
              vertex(agents[j].location.x, agents[j].location.y,1.0,1.0);//bottom right texture coordinat
              endShape(CLOSE);
              j=300;
            }
          }
        }
        /*void triangulate()
         {

         fill(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 40));

         stroke(140, 50);
         for (int i=0; i<numAgents; i++)
         {
         //gens[i].connect==true)
         //if(! agents[i].connect)

         if (agents[i].behaviour==1)

         {
         //println(agents[i]);
         int k;

         k=1;

         for (int j=0; j<numAgents; j++)
         {
         float dm = dist(agents[i].location.x, agents[i].location.y, agents[j].location.x, agents[j].location.y);
         // float dm = agents[i].location.dist(agents[j].location);
         // int clr=(int) map (dm,0,100,200,0);
         if (dm<180 && dm>100)

         {
         if ( k<2)
         {
         //println(dm);
         //stroke(255,0,0);
         }
         }
         }
         }*/
      }
    }
  }
}
int numMovers= 1;
Mover[]movers= new Mover[numMovers];

class Mover
{

  PVector location;
  PVector velocity;
  PVector acceleration;
  float topspeed;
  boolean hit = false;

  Mover() 
  {
    float spead = 800;
    location = new PVector(random(0,spead),random(0,spead));
    velocity = new PVector(0,0);
    acceleration = new PVector(random(-1,1),random(-1,1));//random initial acceleration
    topspeed = 4;
  }



  void update() 
  {
    // Motion 101!  Velocity changes by acceleration.  Location changes by velocity.
    velocity.add(acceleration);
    velocity.limit(topspeed);
    location.add(velocity);
  }


  void display()
  {
    pushMatrix();
  translate(location.x,location.y);
  //fill(102,0,155,random(120,160));
  //fill(32,225,245,127 + sin(frameCount*.01) * 127);
  if(hit) fill(255,10,96,120);
  else   
  fill(3,225,190,random(50,127));
  ellipse(0,0,30,30);
  noStroke();
  popMatrix();
  }


  void checkEdges() 
  {

    if(location.x < 0){
      location.x = 0;
      velocity.x *= -1;
      acceleration.mult(0.001);
    }
    if(location.x > 800){
      location.x = 800;
      velocity.x *= -1;
      acceleration.mult(0.001);

    }
    if(location.y < 0){
      location.y = 0;
      velocity.y *=- 1;
      acceleration.mult(0.001);

    }
    if(location.y > 800){
      location.y = 800;
      velocity.y *= -1;
      acceleration.mult(0.001);

    }




  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot George! It was really helpful your answer!